# Sparking from multiple receptacles on circuit

Tags: electrical

Last night, I noticed audible pops and sparking inside two receptacles on the same circuit. This circuit also powers a bathroom vent fan. Could a bad outlet or hardwired device on a circuit cause sparking in other receptacles on that circuit, or should I be looking elsewhere for the problem?

Comment: Can you describe the sparking in more detail?  Was anything being plugged/unplugged?  Was anything connected to the receptacles?  Was the sparking visible through the slots or some other way?

Comment: Yes, under what circumstances are you getting receptacle sparking? During plug/unplug, or just with something running?  Is it visible at/thru the slots, or are you hearing sparking coming from deeper within?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel this sparking occurred without anything on the circuit being plugged or unplugged or turned off/on. One of the outlets is a GFCI but I believe it is downstream of the other regular outlet that sparked. It seems to be arcing inside the outlet boxes.

Comment: I would start by turning off the breaker to ensure there is no more potential fire starting!

Comment: Probably the infamous back stab outlets failing. Turn off the power and, pull the outlets and inspect for arcing, melting, etc. If back-stab (where the wires are poked into holes in the back of the outlet), convert to pig-tails and connect to the screws on the side of the outlet.  Perhaps also a good idea to replace the outlets with high quality units....they are only a few bucks and worth it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson would that be likely to cause a couple of different outlets to spark at about the same time?

Comment: @Marcatectura  Could be.  Are there any new loads on the circuit, especially like an electric heater? Computer? Microwave?   These are tough problems to solve remotely. Again, all I can suggest is to turn off the power, remove the recalcitrant outlets and inspect for damage, melting, arcing, etc., refit for pigtails vs. backstabs.